# mu4e Setup: cannot create messages outside the Drafts mailbox Error

Tags: mu4e, email

I am attempting to setup mu4e to read mail from a Protonmail account. I'm using `offlineimap` to sync my mail dirs. However, when I try to refile or move a message from my INBOX folder to any other folder that I sync with the server I get an error like this in offlineimap:

```
Server responded: NO ['cannot create messages outside the Drafts mailbox']
```

I'm surprised that there's not much that I can find on this error. Since it doesn't seem to be a common offlineimap error I have to wonder if it has something to do with the way that mu4e moves messages around?

Here's how I can reproduce the error:

0. Receive a new message in my inbox
1. Sync my local maildir with my Protonmail account successfully using offlineimap (which points at a hydroxide process)
2. Run `mu index`
3. Open mu4e and refile the message to my Archive folder
4. Attempt to sync my mailbox again using offlineimap

Here is my .offlineimaprc file:

```
# ~/.offlineimaprc

[general]
accounts = protonmail
pythonfile = ~/.config/offlineimap/keyring.py
metadata = ~/.cache/offlineimap

[Account protonmail]
remoterepository = protonmail-remote
localrepository = protonmail-local

[Repository protonmail-local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/.mail
sync_deletes = yes


[Repository protonmail-remote]
# delete local mails that were deleted on the remote server
expunge = yes
type = IMAP
remotehost = 127.0.0.1
remoteport= 1143
remoteuser = tompurl
remotepasseval = get_password("tompurl@protonmail.com")

folderfilter = lambda foldername: foldername in ['INBOX', 'Archive', 'Sent']
ssl = no
```

...and here's my mu4e config:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/tom/.nix-profile/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu4e")
(require 'mu4e)

(setq mu4e-maildir "~/.mail"
      mu4e-attachment-dir "~/Downloads")

(setq mu4e-sent-folder   "/Sent")
(setq mu4e-drafts-folder "/Drafts")
(setq mu4e-refile-folder "/Archive")
(setq mu4e-trash-folder  "/Trash")

(setq user-mail-address "tom@tompurl.com"
      user-full-name  "Tom Purl")

;; Get mail
(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "offlineimap"
      mu4e-change-filenames-when-moving nil
      mu4e-update-interval nil)

;; Send mail
(setq message-send-mail-function     'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-auth-credentials "~/.authinfo.gpg"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "127.0.0.1"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 1025)
```

Here's what I've tried:

0. Set `mu4e-change-filenames-when-moving` to true, which is apparently necessary for mbsync but not offlineimap.
1. Set `sync_deletes` in my .offlineimaprc file to "no".

Otherwise I'm just stumped. I'm surprised that this isn't a much more common error because my setup is pretty vanilla.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue using hydroxide/offlineimap/mu4e and poking through the issues for hydroxide on github brought me to [the last entry by emersion for issue 30](https://github.com/emersion/hydroxide/issues/30), who says:

> Kind of. When sending a message, the ProtonMail API requires the client to create a draft message then send it (that'll implicitly copy it to Sent).
>
> To copy and add new messages in arbitrary folders we'd need to use the import API. Some WIP code for this is in https://github.com/emersion/hydroxide/blob/master/protonmail/import.go.

This may be the cause of the issue.